# exe dbo.SearchAllTables '12345678' - ? how do we search for multiple text?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlite, postgresql

```
exe dbo.SearchAllTables '12345678'
```

I need a query to search multiple items; items like `12345678, 78945641, 14725836` in all tables in the database. The above query works only for single text search.

Comment: Pass in additional parameters to your stored proc?

Comment: Need clarification: Which table, what do you search for, what do you mean by items, what do you mean by all tables. Also post you stored procedure code too.

Comment: We have few customer numbers in different tables across database. So what we need is we need to know all the tables where these customer numbers are present. We have totally 622 customer numbers. The query which we gave: exe dbo.SearchAllTables '12345678' , gave us output only for this particular customer number. We have multiple customer numbers and we need to run a query at one shot to find all the customers. For eg: exe dbo.SearchAllTables '12345678' , '32165498', '55447788'. is there a way to do it?

Comment: In other words, we need to search multiple string across database tables. Can you help us in getting the query.

Comment: @JayachandranE Please edit your question and put **much** more detail such as table structure, sample data and expected output. Also reduce the tags: this seems sql-server related so remove other DBMS tags.

Comment: When I run the below query “exe dbo.SearchAllTables '12345678'” in SQL, I get the below output:
ColumnName ColumnValue
[dbo].[CPCI].[CNO] 9000147
[dbo].[CPCI].[CNO] 9000147
[dbo].[CPCI].[CNO] 9000147
[dbo].[CPCI].[CNO] 9000147
[dbo].[CPCI].[CNO] 9000147
[dbo].[CRGM].[GRPMEMBER] 9000147
[dbo].[CSPI].[CNO] 9000147
[dbo].[CSPI].[CNO] 9000147
[dbo].[CSRI].[CUST] 9000147

Now, we need a query to find out for multiple numbers like '12345678', ‘55544455’, ‘44788855’. The above query is only for single string search. What is the query for multiple string searches?

Comment: I think `exe` should be `exec`, and your SP is in SQL Server, so delete other DMBS tags ;).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a clue in your stored procedure with `@Find` input like this:

```
SET @query = @query + 'WHERE [value] Like ''%' + @Find + '%'''
EXEC(@query)
```

Now your input is like this `@Find = '12345678, 78945641, 14725836'`, So you should change your code to of these:

If you want to find exact values:

```
SET @query = @query + 'WHERE [value] IN (''' + REPLACE(@Find, ',', ''',''') + ''')'
EXEC(@query)
```

If you want to find containing values:

```
SET @query = @query + 'WHERE [value] Like ''%' + REPLACE(@Find, ',', '%'' OR [value] Like ''%') + '%'''
EXEC(@query)
```